# Material-UI: Remove TimelineItem missingOppositeContent:before element

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI and building a timeline. My code is as follows:

```
<Timeline align="right" className={classes.monthlyContainer}>
    <TimelineItem >
        <TimelineSeparator className={classes.timelineSeparator}>
            <TimelineDot className={classes.timelineDot} />
            <TimelineConnector className={classes.timelineConnector} />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        {(data.map(url =>
            <TimelineContent className={classes.memsImageContainer}>
                <img
                    className={classes.memsImage}
                    src={url}
                    alt="MEMs"
                />
            </TimelineContent>
        ))}
    </TimelineItem>
</Timeline>
```

When I render the webpage, the Material-UI timeline keeps creating a `.MuiTimelineItem-missingOppositeContent:before` element which is shifting the layout of my timeline to the left.

When I inspect the element, this is what I see:

[image]

```
<li class="MuiTimelineItem-root MuiTimelineItem-alignRightMuiTimelineItem-missingOppositeContent">
    <div class="MuiTimelineSeparator-root makeStyles-timelineSeparator-4">
        <span class="MuiTimelineDot-root makeStyles-timelineDot-5 MuiTimelineDot-defaultGrey">
        </span>
        <span class="MuiTimelineConnector-root makeStyles-timelineConnector-6">
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

When I inspect the styles, this is what I have:

```
.MuiTimelineItem-missingOppositeContent:before {
    flex: 1;
    content: "";
    padding: 6px 16px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
```

I have recreated it in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-pascal-7xdmi?file=/src/App.js)

How can I remove this element?

Comment: could you reproduce this problem on codesandbox?

Comment: I've just recreated this and added the link to my question. As you can see there is whitespace on the right of the timeline where the empty `MuiListItem` is with it's gutters that have a padding to the left of 6px and right of 16px.

Comment: @Ryan - I've updated and added now. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: @Ryan - apologies if this isn't clear in my question but the issue is that MUI is creating the element in question from the Timeline API that I'm using, which is why it doesn't appear in my code in the sandbox.

Comment: @Ryan - I've added an image to the question to clarify

Comment: You're right - I've misread the code and mistaken `MuiTimelineItem` for `MuiListItem`. However I still can't get rid of the `MuiTimelineItem-missingOppositeContent` element which is causing all the problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definition of the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/TimelineItem/TimelineItem.js#L36) for the `missingOppositeContent` element is as follows:

```
  /* Styles applied to the root element if no there isn't TimelineOppositeContent provided. */
  missingOppositeContent: {
    '&:before': {
      content: '""',
      flex: 1,
      padding: '6px 16px',
    },
  },
```

You can override the default styles using the same structure. Overriding this in the theme would look like the following:

```
const Theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTimelineItem: {
      missingOppositeContent: {
        "&:before": {
          display: "none"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Remove missing opposite content - theme]

You can also do this on a case-by-case basis (in case you have other situations in your code where you want the missing-opposite-content styling) using `withStyles`:

```
const TimelineItem = withStyles({
  missingOppositeContent: {
    "&:before": {
      display: "none"
    }
  }
})(MuiTimelineItem);
```

[image: Edit Remove missing opposite content - withStyles]

Comment: Thank you Ryan - Apologies for all the confusion - I've had two css issues I'm trying to resolve (hence the two questions) and got confused between the two!

Answer (score 3):

You won't believe that you just need to add the `<TimelineOppositeContent>` component and set `display` property as 'none'. And it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution i found it in the documentation [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-timeline/) you can just do this

```
 import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
 import TimelineItem, { timelineItemClasses } from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
    
 return <Timeline
         sx={{
              [`& .${timelineItemClasses.root}:before`]: {
                    flex: 0,
                    padding: 0,
              },
            }}
        >
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).